# C# method foreach

Tags: c#, methods

```
public string GetNetworkAdapterName()
    {
            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in name.Get())
            {
                bool physicaladapter = Convert.ToBoolean(queryObj["PhysicalAdapter"]);
                if (physicaladapter == true)
                {
                    return Convert.ToString(queryObj["Name"]);
                }
            }
            return null;
    }
```

How can I get for example the first, second element of the foreach ?
GetNetworkadapterName(1) is not working
thanks

Comment: Why you d not use for, or try some iterator int i and boolean first and second and save the elements

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you're trying to do. Of courseGetNetworkadapterName(1) won't work - the method doesn't have any parameters... you're also referring to "the foreach" as if it's an object... please clarify what your goal is.

Comment: for index based operations you should use for loop instead of foreach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the current code will always return the first physical adapter.  to modify it to allow you to tell it which to return, try something like this:

```
public string GetNetworkAdapterName(int Ordinal)
    {
            int i = 1;

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in name.Get())
            {
                bool physicaladapter = Convert.ToBoolean(queryObj["PhysicalAdapter"]);
                if (physicaladapter == true && i == Ordinal)
                {
                    return Convert.ToString(queryObj["Name"]);
                } else if (physicaladapter == true) { 
                    i++;
                }
            }
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: yeah, i just realized it a minute ago fixed now.

Comment: @chuck, that would have to be a separate function.  is this homework?

Comment: i voted not down, and no it is not homework, first i created a list, but i read that i shouldn't do this with a list and so i wanted to now hot this works, thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

It's very unclear what you're trying to do, but if the idea is to allow the caller to find *all* the network adapters, you can use LINQ (if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher):

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetNetworkAdapterNames()
{
    return name.Get()
               .Cast<ManagementObject>() // May not be necessary
               .Where(q => Convert.ToBoolean(q["PhysicalAdapter"]))
               .Select(q => Convert.ToString(q["Name"]));
}
```

If you're not using .NET 3.5, you could use an iterator block to do the same thing slightly more manually.

Then the caller can decide what to do with the sequence of adapter names - they could find the n<sup>th</sup> one, or print all of them out etc. This has the advantage that if they *do* want to access multiple elements, they can do so efficiently.

Getting to the n<sup>th</sup> value will always take iteration, but this can be hidden with a convenience method, such as LINQ's `ElementAt` method:

```
string secondAdapterName = GetNetworkAdapterNames().ElementAt(1);
```

I firmly believe that mixing the concern of "finding the n<sup>th</sup> value" with that of "finding all the network adapter names" is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

you can use an integer like this:

```
   int i = 0;
    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in name.Get())
    {
         i++;
         if(i < 3)
          {/*get element*/}            
          bool physicaladapter = Convert.ToBoolean(queryObj["PhysicalAdapter"]); 
            if (physicaladapter == true)
            {
                 return Convert.ToString(queryObj["Name"]);
            }  
    }
    return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public string GetNetworkAdapterName(int index)
{
    ManagementObject[] queryObjects = name.Get();
    if(index > queryObjects.Length)
        return String.Empty;
    ManagementObject queryObj = queryObjects[index];
    if(Convert.ToBoolean(queryObj["PhysicalAdapter"]))
        return queryObj["Name"].toString();
    else
        return String.Empty;      
}
```